# Find values from Xml who have same Element Name

Tags: c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have following  xml which same child element (Filed) and I want to get value from each Child element.

Sameple XML

```
 <root xmlns="">
    <books cat="F1" ISBN="01F187597" genre="Programming">
      <Field name="Title" val="XML" /> 
      <Field name="Publish Date" val="20010424" /> 
      <Field name="Price" val="43.00" /> 
    </books>
 </root>
```

Code

```
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("c:\\test6.xml");

  var booksData = from book in xdoc.Descendants("root")
                  //I guess create this and do something with it
                  // let fieldElements = book.Descendants("Field")
                  select new Book
                  {
                         cat = book.Element("books").Attribute("cat").Value
                         ,ISBN = book.Element("books").Attribute("ISBN").Value
                         ,genre = book.Element("books").Attribute("genre").Value
                         ,Price = "?"
                         ,PublishDate="?"
                         ,Title="?"
                   };
```

Book Class

```
 public class Book
  {
    public string cat {get;set;}
    public string ISBN {get;set;}
    public string genre {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string PublishDate {get;set;}
    public string Price { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Dennis xdoc.Descendants("root") doesn't really do anything.

I modify code so it will check attrbiute exists or not also how you can use lambda expression.

```
  var booksData = from book in xdoc.Descendants("books")
                            select new Book
                            {
                                cat = book.Attribute("cat").Value,
                                ISBN = book.Attribute("ISBN").Value,
                                genre = book.Attribute("genre").Value,

                                //Dennis Code 

                               Price = (from childField in book.Elements()
                                         where childField.Attribute("name").Value == "Price"
                                         select childField.Attribute("val").Value).SingleOrDefault(),

                                //same as Dennis code but using lambda expression

                                PublishDate = book.Elements("Field").Where(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Publish Date")
                                              .Select(p => p.Attribute("val").Value).SingleOrDefault(),

                                 // Check if element exists or not 
                                 //if not exists it will insert empty string

                               Title = book.Elements("Field").Any( p => p.Attribute("name").Value == "Title")
                                        ? book.Elements("Field").Where(p=> p.Attribute("name").Value == "Title")
                                          .Select(p => p.Attribute("val")== null
                                                  ? string.Empty
                                                  : p.Attribute("val").Value
                                                  ).Single()
                                        : string.Empty                                };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you're looking for. Of course, if there is a possibility of any of these attributes not always being present, you'd want to add some null value checks to make sure each attribute exists before calling it's `Value` property.

Once you have the `<books>` element inside your query, you can do sub queries to select the specific `<Field>` elements that you need.

```
var booksData = from book in xdoc.Descendants("books")
                select new Book
                           {
                               cat = book.Attribute("cat").Value,
                               ISBN = book.Attribute("ISBN").Value,
                               genre = book.Attribute("genre").Value,
                               Price = (from childField in book.Elements()
                                        where childField.Attribute("name").Value == "Price"
                                        select childField.Attribute("val").Value).SingleOrDefault(),
                               PublishDate = (from childField in book.Elements()
                                              where childField.Attribute("name").Value == "Publish Date"
                                              select childField.Attribute("val").Value).SingleOrDefault(),
                               Title = (from childField in book.Elements()
                                        where childField.Attribute("name").Value == "Title"
                                        select childField.Attribute("val").Value).SingleOrDefault()
                           };
```

One note on the code you posted in the question. The method `xdoc.Descendants("root")` doesn't really do anything. `from book in xdoc` would do the same thing. I used `Descendants("books")` in my answer, which is what I think you meant to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
string xml = @"<root xmlns=''>    <books cat='F1' ISBN='01F187597' genre='Programming'>      <Field name='Title' val='XML' />       <Field name='Publish Date' val='20010424' />       <Field name='Price' val='43.00' />     </books> </root>";



            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var booksData = from book in xdoc.Descendants("root")
                            //I guess create this and do something with it
                            // let fieldElements = book.Descendants("Field")
                            select new Book
                            {
                                cat = book.Element("books").Attribute("cat").Value
                                   , ISBN = book.Element("books").Attribute("ISBN").Value
                                   , genre = book.Element("books").Attribute("genre").Value
                                   , Price = book.Elements("books").Elements("Field").Single(b => b.Attribute("name").Value == "Price").Attribute("val").Value
                                   , PublishDate = book.Elements("books").Elements("Field").Single(b => b.Attribute("name").Value == "Publish Date").Attribute("val").Value
                                   , Title = book.Elements("books").Elements("Field").Single(b => b.Attribute("name").Value == "Title").Attribute("val").Value
                            };

        }


        public class Book
        {
            public string cat { get; set; }
            public string ISBN { get; set; }
            public string genre { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string PublishDate { get; set; }
            public string Price { get; set; }
        }
```

I think this is how I would do it.

Comment: your  code will not work in following scenario
if attribute val is missing  e.g.
 <Field name="Title" /> 

OR Title element missing 

<root xmlns="">
<books cat="F1" ISBN="01F187597" genre="Fantasy">
   <Field name="Publish Date" val="20010424" /> 
  <Field name="Price" val="43" /> 
    </books>
  </root>